# Swift: Typhoon DI + NSViewController in XIB + OSX - How to inject

Tags: macos, xib, nib, typhoon

I'm using View Controllers included in XIBs (OSX app, not iOS) and I need to inject some properties. Is there better way to inject them?

```
/**
Inject properties from typhoon
*/
override func viewDidLoad() {
    TyphoonComponentFactory.defaultFactory().inject(self)
}
```

Here is the assembly definition:

```
public dynamic func assemblyTaskGroupViewController() -> AnyObject
{
    return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(TaskGroupViewController.self) {
        (definition) in
        definition.injectProperty("projectManager", with: self.projectManager())
        definition.injectProperty("timeTrackService", with: self.timeTrackService())

        definition.scope = TyphoonScope.LazySingleton
    }

}
```

For the assembly initialization, I use plist integration.

Comment: Can you show how a view controller is instantiated and perhaps a screenshot of a XIB?